# Pull amplitude from system audio output with cpal

Tags: rust

I am trying to process live system audio using cpal in Rust. This is a simplified version for now and part of a bigger project. In theory, the `build_input_stream_raw()` data_callback would return a vector of `f32` amplitudes from eg. a song/video/stream. However the data (`&cpal::Data`) returned is always `0.0`.

```
use cpal::traits::{DeviceTrait, HostTrait, StreamTrait};

pub fn main() {
    let host = cpal::default_host();

    let device = host.default_input_device().unwrap();

    let config = device
        .default_input_config()
        .expect("Failed to get default input config");

    let sample_format = config.sample_format();

    let err_fn = move |err| {
        eprintln!("an error occurred on stream: {}", err);
    };

    let stream = device
        .build_input_stream_raw(
            &config.into(),
            sample_format,
            move |data: &cpal::Data, cb: &cpal::InputCallbackInfo| {
                // amplitudes as f32 vec
            },
            err_fn,
            None,
        )
        .unwrap();

    stream.play().unwrap();

    std::thread::sleep(std::time::Duration::from_secs(10));
    drop(stream);
}
```

I already read the documentation and multiple universal cpal examples online, without any significant progress. My current solution does not rely on null sinks, as I want it to be as universal as possible.
If there is a better tool for that purpose, I am open for suggestions.

cpal version: 0.15.0
audio system: ALSA